# Hibernate mappings not found when deployed to Oracle app server?

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, classpath, hibernate-mapping

I'm having an issue with Hibernate resources not being found when deployed within an `jar` file on Oracle application server.

I have some hibernate mapping files defined in `LocalSessionFactoryBean` as follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  <property name="mappingLocations">
    <list>
       <value>classpath:/mapping/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
```

This bean definition is in a file `applicationContext.xml`.

The hibernate mappings, the classes referenced by these mappings, and the `applicationContext.xml` file are located in module `foo`, which generates artifact `foo.jar`.

I created a `.ear` that references `foo.jar` and uses the same `applicationContext.xml` file. When I deploy that `.ear` to Oracle application server I see the following error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mapping/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: code-source:/.../oas10.1.3/j2ee/.../applications/.../WEB-INF/lib/foo.jar!mapping/`

When I examine `/WEB-INF/lib/foo.jar` I can see the `mappings` directory with Hibernate mapping files as expected.

As a sanity check I created a simple project with a dependency on `foo` and which runs the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class AppTest {

  @Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Test
  public void loadObjects() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<Foo> results = session.createQuery("from Foo").list();
    System.out.println("found " + results.size() + " results");
  }
}
```

This works as expected: the HQL query runs and I get back the correct number of Foo objects from the database.

So why does that simple application referencing the mapping resources in `foo.jar` work, but doing the same thing on Oracle app server leads to resources not found?

edit: I tried using `mappingJarLocations` instead of `mappingLocations`:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  <property name="mappingJarLocations">
    <list>
       <value>WEB-INF/lib/foo.jar</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
```

and got a `FileNotFoundException`.

**edit:** I went back to using `mappingLocations` instead of `mappingJarLocations` (as in my first example), but this time I copied my `*.hbm.xml` files directly to the `.war` file's `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Not surprisingly, this worked:

`setMappingLocations() - file:/.../oas10.1.3/j2ee/.../applications/.../raps-site-9.0/WEB-INF/classes/mapping/Address.hbm.xml`

I will try utility jars as suggested, but as a temporary measure I'll modify my `pom.xml` to copy the mappings directly to `WEB-INF/classes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to package the jar inside the ear itself. Such jars are called utility jars.

They are several possible way to do this, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/1211_schrag/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently `foo.jar` exists in a `bar.war` file that is then put into the `.ear`. When deployed, a `WEB-INF/lib/foo.jar` file exists. Is creating a utility jar still required?

Comment: AFAIK the utility jar must be in the root of `.ear` and referenced is the manifest of `bar.war`
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828781/architecture-of-a-java-ee-project or http://www.coderanch.com/t/309491/EJB-JEE/java/utility-JAR-EAR-WAR

Comment: Actually I specified a `mappingJarLocations` property with `file:**/foo.jar` and this seems to do the trick. But now I get `unknown entity` exceptions. Two steps forward, one step back ...

Comment: I will keep investigating the use of utility jars in an `.ear` file.